# How do you call an external C function from a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, functions, errors, teradata

In Teradata 17, I am trying to call their own `hash_md5` external function from my own SQL stored procedure:

```
replace procedure p()
sql security creator
begin
  declare l_hash varchar(32);
  set l_hash = hash_md5('abc');
end;

call p();
```

I get:

> Failed [3706 : 42000] P:Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the string 'abc'.

I can call this function successfully in plain SQL:

```
select hash_md5('abc');
```

> 900150983CD24FB0D6963F7D28E17F72

I tried to pass a parameter in, instead of a hardcoded literal, but it made no difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`hash_md5` is a C-UDF, which must be installed. Without qualified object name it will only be found if it's created in TD_SYSFNLIB or SYSLIB or the current session default database.

This should work:

```
set l_hash = mydb.hash_md5('abc');
```